# Use js/jquery to scroll to nth child of div so nth child is on bottom, not top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Same story you've heard a thousand times: I've got a `div` that contains a list of events and I want it to scroll through this list. However, in the answers I've looked at, the approach is to always get the `nth-child` to the top of the div, and not the bottom. Because I want my users to focus on the past elements and not the future, I'd prefer the child to be at the bottom. Here is the code I'm currently utilizing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Help Me, I'm New...</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style = "text-align: center;"><h1 id = "title">My First Web Application</h1></div>
    <div>
      <iframe src = "plot0.html" width = 80%% height = 1100px id = "sankey" style = "border: none; float: left;"></iframe>
      <div style = "float: left; overflow: auto; height: 800px; width: 20%%; border: 1px;" id = "events"></div>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          var selector = $("#sankey");
          var delay_sec = 1.5;
          var num = 1, 
              len = 84;
          var events = [array_of_events];
          for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            $("#events").append(events[i]);
          }
          setInterval(function() {
            num = (num === len) ? 0 : num;
            selector.attr("src", "plot" + num + ".html");
            $("h3:lt(" + num + ")").css("color", "#000000");
            $("h3:nth-of-type(" + num + ")").css("color", "#FF6A6A");
            $("p:lt(" + num + ")").css("color", "#000000");
            $("p:nth-of-type(" + num + ")").css("color", "#FF6A6A");
            $("#events").scrollTop($("#events h3:nth-of-type(" + num + ")").position().top - $("#events h3:first").position().top);
            num++;
          }, delay_sec * 1000);
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The line that starts `$("#events").scrollTop` is what I want to fix.

***EDIT***
I should probably point out that each element in `array_of_events` looks like this: `<h6>2015-11-05</h6><p>brittenb offers reputation to whomever answers this question</p>`

I know how to scroll to the bottom of the div (but that's too far) and I know how to put the child of interest at the top, but that's less than ideal. How do I simply scroll so that the `nth-child` is the last visible element in a div?

***Update***
Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm3bcqdz/). The iframe isn't populating, but that's irrelevant. As you can see, the highlighted `h3` and `p` tags get moved to the top of the div as it scrolls. I would prefer it to be at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a working sample, ideally an snippet or jsfiddle, so that it's possible to focus in the problem and not in the rest of unuseful code in your question? Thank you.

Comment: @JotaBe Yeah, of course. Give me a bit to dummy up some data and get it put together. I'll post the link when it's done.

Comment: I think that it's much easier than that, create the final HTML, and explain what you want the scroll to do.

Comment: @JotaBe I couldn't just post the HTML because the data is confidential. But the link I posted, I believe, demonstrates my issue.

Comment: That's more than enought. I'll try to solve it.

Comment: One quick note that I just realized: the `len` variable should be set to 8, not 84. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You should calculate the total height of the element to show, and all the previous element, and substract the height of the container. That's the scrolltop position that you must use. However, I'm doing so using `outerHeight`, `outerheight(true)`, `height()` and none of the calculations look to match it.

Comment: Using your advice, I set up a threshold set to 0 and every time a "section" (header and paragraph) is highlighted, I get their combined `outerHeight(true)` and add it to the threshold. Once the threshold is greater than or equal to the height of the div, I start a new cumulative sum called height that adds the height of the next section. The output can be seen in the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vm3bcqdz/5/

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do the calculation yourself through JS.

e.g.

- height of your visible div is: `H`
- each of your child element has height `l` (will be more complicated if they are not even in height, but the concept remain)
- `a * l = H`

If you want your `n-th child` to be at the bottom, then you want to set to a scrollTop `T` such that: `T = H - a * l`, which means you should set the scrollTop to the `(n - a)th child`

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm going to try to incorporate this method now and see what I can come up with.